# How do you load a custom JAR into the SceneBuilder that's built into IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, scenebuilder, gluon

I'm trying to load a custom Control into the SceneBuilder that's running inside of IntelliJ. I downloaded the plugin from [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/). In the stand-alone version I have installed, the option to import a custom JAR is available by clicking the gear icon under 'Library'. I see nothing like that when SceneBuilder is run from inside of IntelliJ in a tabbed editor view.

I would think that importing the JAR would allow me to see it show up in IntelliJ, but no such luck. It only shows up when SceneBuilder is ran stand-alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ built-in Scene Builder <del>is not the same as</del> *uses* Gluon's Scene Builder<del>. The former is a version embeddded in the IDE, introduced with IntelliJ IDEA 14, [two years ago](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/javaFX/FxBuilderEmbedder)</del>, but without several features or even menus or recent improvements<del>, while the latter is the complete and [updated](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/) version 8.1.1, that allows you using the latest features available and</del> or adding custom controls, as you have already done.

If you check IntelliJ [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/preparing-for-javafx-application-development.html), they also recommend using the stand-alone version (though they still point to the old 2.0 Oracle's version), they don't refer to the one they embed.

If you want to use custom controls, the only option here is the Gluon's version.

**Note:** I've edited the answer to clarify that IntelliJ built-in Scene Builder *does use* Gluon's Scene Builder, by scanning the content folder with the `dist.jar`. It is recommended having the latest [version](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/#download) installed.